# What actual speed will I get running 333MHz CPU and RAM on a motherboard with a 200MHz FSB?

Tags: fsb

Building a "Frankenstein" PC out of spare parts I have:

- [AMD Sempron 2200+ CPU with 33Mz FSB](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K7/AMD-Sempron%202200+%20-%20SDA2200DUT3D%20%28SDA2200BOX%29.html)
- 2x Kingston 256MB DDR PC2700 333MHz RAM
- Old socket A motherboard with 200MHz FSB.

  1. Will it work
  2. If yes, what actual speed will it run at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your processor will run at 333Mhz internally and at 200MHz communicating to the front side bus.  Its the multiplier that changes, not the speed of the processor.